# Connection refused (os error 111) after few successful Selenium Geckodriver tasks (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 no GUI.

I'm doing a quite simple task there in headless mode:

1. Installing and enabling firefox addon.
2. Navigating to about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox and getting addon's uuid.

The problem is that after a few successful .py script completions, next ones just hang and return Connection refused (os error 111) error. After that I have to reboot the server which fix issue for a few .py script launches only.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
import time

ff_options = FirefoxOptions()

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ff/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"

ff_options.add_argument('-headless')
ff_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
ff_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
ff_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
ff_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
ff_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
ff_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
ff_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
ff_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
ff_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
ff_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
ff_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')

buster = "/root/my_simple_extension.xpi"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/share/geckodriver', options=ff_options)
driver.install_addon(buster, temporary=True)
driver.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver.profile.add_extension(buster)
driver.profile.set_preference("security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy", False)
driver.profile.update_preferences()

driver.get("about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox")

time.sleep(1)

parent1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="fieldpair"])[position()=3]')
uuid = parent1.text.splitlines()[1]

driver.get('moz-extension://{}/home.html'.format(uuid))
time.sleep(1)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

geckodriver.log

```
1632303683203   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:45055
1632303684204   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ff/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "--disable-dev-shm-usage" "--no-sandbox" "--window-size=1920,1080" "--ignore-certificate-errors" "--allow-running-insecure-content" "--proxy-server=\'direct://\'" "--proxy-bypass-list=*" "--start-maximized" "--disable-gpu" "--disable-setuid-sandbox" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilexOejpk"
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
1632303684813   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /tmp/rust_mozprofilexOejpk/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
1632303687471   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 42933
1632303687541   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/background-8.js, line 17: asm.js type error: expecting argument type declaration for 'e' of the form 'arg = arg|0' or 'arg = +arg' or 'arg = fround(arg)'
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://c135a3be-0987-411e-b62f-413239ad2d16/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
1632303696737   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 42933
Port.onMessage event fired while context is inactive.
Port.onMessage event fired while context is inactive.
Port.onMessage event fired while context is inactive.
JavaScript error: resource:///modules/Interactions.jsm, line 230: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIUserIdleService.removeIdleObserver]
```

Comment: how often you run it ? Do you run many instances in short time? Maybe previous version is still in memory and it makes problem. Maybe you should check running processes and kill them if there is still firefox in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you *furas* for getting me on the track. It appears that after some python code error, driver.quit() wasn't executed which lead to multiple hanging firefox processes. Quitting them with **sudo pkill -9 firefox** solved the issue.

Comment: By default geckodriver uses a random free port to determine to which instance of Firefox to connect to. So a situation like the one from above shouldn't happen. But hard-coding to a specific Marionette port might cause issues. As such make sure to leave it using defaults. You could inspect the geckodriver trace log file to check that.

By default I use pytest as harness for running my tests. And to enforce that clean-up steps like `driver.quit()` always run a `pytest.fixture` for the driver that is in use. If you aren't using pytest, you may use the `try / finally` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Having just the source code of the test doesn't really help to give a qualified answer for your issue. As such please [create trace logs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/TraceLogs.html) while the test is running and share these with us. The additional information as logged to a file (should be geckodriver.log in your case) can help to understand the situation, and finally to propose a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the question with log file